# Convert UTC to Unix Timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, date, time, icalendar

I'm parsing an RSS feed which has the time and date as UTC, I need to convert this into a unix timestamp. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php